# Create a binary tree if preorder and postorder traversals are given in JAVA?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I wanted to known can we create exact binary tree from preorder and postorder traversals only.If yes how (clear algorithm required) or If no why NOT?

Comment: Can you show us the code/work you have done until now? If not, I charge 40$/hour (Slightly negotiable).

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot create an exact binary tree from preorder and postorder only as you would never be able to estimate the left/right child of the tree.

You need the *inorder* traversal along with the any of the above.

```
For example : 

    consider PreOrder : AB
             PostOrder : BA

    Tree can be as follows : 
              A   or     A
             /            \ 
            B              B
```

But if the given tree is a Full Binary tree, than you can construct the tree from given traversals. See [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/full-and-complete-binary-tree-from-given-preorder-and-postorder-traversals/).